# Wireless Network connects to one network, disconnects from it, connects to other network, then connects to previous network and does this infinitely

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

I have the following Wireless Adpater [Intel Centrino] on my Windows 7 Professional laptop:

[image: Device manager snapshot]

I have tried resetting it many times, and this problem persists.

I remember, I might have added two wireless networks and clicked on `'Auto Connect'` check box for both networks few days ago. And these two networks 'A' and 'B' refer to the connection from the same wireless router.

Now, the adapter is infinitely repeating the following loop:

1. It connects to wireless network named 'A'
2. After 2 seconds, it disconnects from 'A'
3. After another 2 seconds, it connects to network named 'B'
4. Then it again disconnects from 'B'
5. And then it starts from point 1 again..

When I search in the `Manage Wireless Networks` in `Network and Sharing Center`, I don't have the 'A' and 'B' listed there, so I am unable to remove them.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure of the cause of this issue, because AFAIK Windows only changes the wireless network it's connected to if it gets manually instructed to, or gets disassociated from the network it's currently on.

A way to remove A or B as networks you connect to may be to use the command line and netsh.

From a command prompt, run the following, for the network which you want to delete.

`netsh wlan delete profile name="A"`

If successful, you should get `Profile "A" is deleted from interface "Wireless Network Connection"`

If unsuccessful, you may get `Profile "A" is not found on any interface`

If you are unable to delete the network using the above method, it may be that the network has been configured by your systems administrator using group policy. If this is the case, you will need to discuss it with your IT team in order to get A or B removed from group policy.

Comment: I have tried deleting these two network using command lines and got a message that both are deleted, but the issue is still there. It is still connecting/disconnecting from both infinitely.

Comment: Hmmm. If you try and delete them from the command line again, does it say it has deleted them again? Or that they don't exist? It sounds like some other piece of software may be manipulating/controlling your wireless connections.

Comment: Yes, there was another software from Intel that was installed on my system. Removing profiles from that software did the work.